# How to generate div element ids in for loop JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop

I am trying to generate a preset number of div elements in a loop in JavaScript or JQuery. The goal is to have to loop create these divs with an id that I can use to reference in another part of the program. I understand that I cannot use concatenation with DOM. So, I am having difficulty getting it to execute. I've tried doing this with a document fragment, but I'm not very familiar with them. Here is some pseudocode of what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
numCards = 16;

for (var i = 0; i < numCards; i++)
{
     html += '<div id="image' + i + '"><img src="images/desiredImage.png"></div>'
}
```

Again, I understand that this will not work because I can't use concatenation in a loop in this way. What other methods may be useful for this problem?

Comment: attach your html code where to generate elements inside.

Comment: You can absolutely concatenate like that in a loop.  Provided `html` is a variable containing a string.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML)

```js
numCards = 16;
let html = "";
for (var i = 0; i < numCards; i++)
{
     html += '<div id="image' + i + '"><img src="images/desiredImage.png"></div>'
}

document.getElementById("parent").innerHTML = html;
```

```html
<div id="parent">
<div>
```

Comment: I am using a jQuery click function to try to log the id of the image clicked. The content of the function is: var thisId = $("#parent : first-child").attr('id');    console.log(thisId);   and I keep getting "image0" as the output. Any ideas?

Comment: attach your jquery code to trigger the click function. fyi, #parent:first-child will always return the first child. what do you want exactly?

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for `node.appendChild(myDiv);` ([appendChild()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild))

So for this loop I would recommend:

```
const numCards = 16;
const parent = document.getElementById('parentDiv');

for (var i = 0; i < numCards; i++)
{
    // using template literals is cleaner
    const div = `<div id="image${i}"><img src="images/desiredImage.png"></div>`
    
    // append the new div to the parent
    parent.appendChild(div);
}
```

Comment: Appending within a loop is discouraged as, in a general practice, you want to touch the DOM as little as possible.  It is better to create a document fragment, append to that, and then after the loop append the fragment to the DOM

Answer (score 0):

```
numCards = 16;

const parent = document.querySelector("#parent")

for (var i = 0; i < numCards; i++)
{
     html += `<div id="image${i}"><img src="images/desiredImage.png"></div>`
     parent.insertAdjacentHTML("afterbegin",html)
}
```

Notice That I am using backticks `` and curly braces with the dollar sign

Backticks replaces the quotation marks

The Dollar signs means that you want to append some random or special content here

The Curly braces is the container for the special content

Answer (score 0):

**instead of defining the length of the cards let jQuery do the work (its really up to you actually). Here is my solution.**

```js
var card_parent = jQuery(document).find('div.card_parent');
    var numCards = card_parent.children('div.numCards').length;
    console.log( numCards + ': total cards'); //this is your number of cards in page

    jQuery('div.numCards').each(function( card_count )
    {
      console.log( 'card ' + card_count + ' id => ' + jQuery(this).attr('id') );
      
      card_count++;
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div class="card_parent"><!-- add a parent that nest the number of cards -->
      <div id="card_1" class="numCards">card 1</div><!--for each class uses a singular class -->
      <div id="card_2" class="numCards">card 2</div>
      <div id="card_3" class="numCards">card  3</div>
      <div id="card_4" class="numCards">card  4</div>
      <div id="card_5" class="numCards">card  5</div>
      <div id="card_6" class="numCards">card  6</div>
      <div id="card_7" class="numCards">card  7</div>
      <div id="card_8" class="numCards">card  8</div>
      <div id="card_9" class="numCards">card  9</div>
      <div id="card_10" class="numCards">card  10</div>
      <div id="card_11" class="numCards">card  11</div>
      <div id="card_12" class="numCards">card  12</div>
      <div id="card_13" class="numCards">card  13</div>
      <div id="card_14" class="numCards">card  14</div>
      <div id="card_15" class="numCards">card  15</div>
      <div id="it_works" class="numCards">card  16</div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend using a function

```js
const createDiv = (id, textContent) =>
  Object.assign
    ( document.createElement("div")
    , { id, textContent }
    )
    
const items =
  [ { key: "one", value: "bird" }
  , { key: "two", value: "worm" }
  , { key: "three", value: "cat" }
  , { key: "four", value: "mouse" }
  ]
 
const target =
  document.body
  
for (const item of items)
  target.appendChild(createDiv(item.key, item.value))
```

```css
#one { color: green; }
#two { color: blue; }
#three { color: orange; }
#four { color: red; }
```

Output

[image: Output]